# Deployment of smart contract for research. Infura, Truffle or Metamask (which is more practical)?

Tags: blockchain, metamask, infura, truffle-contract

Truffle, Infura, Metamask which is more practical way to deploy smart contracts for research purposes? Can someone explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest quick win, IMHO. Not the most practical tooling for ambitious projects.

1. Simple contract.
2. Compile in remix ide, web based.
3. My ether wallet, to deploy contract
4. Metamask to sign the deployment transaction. You need a little eth to pay for gas. Remix provides the bytecode.
5. Save the abi (remix provides it) You will need it.

Hope it helps